# Create a Detail Report by Proc Report

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a Detail Report by Proc Report. I wrote this code:

```
ods pdf file = "D:\New folder (2)\Assignment\Case_Study_1\Detail_Report.pdf";                                                        

   proc report data =  Cs1.Detailed_Report headline;                                                                                    

   Title 'Olympic Pipeline (LONDON) - by Probability As of 17th November 2012';                                                         

   column Probability Account_Name Opportunity_Owner Last_Modified_Date Total_Media_Value Digital_Total_Media_Value Deal_Comments;      

   where Probability > 0;                                                                                                               

   define Probability/group Descending 'Probability';                                                                                   

   define Account_Name/across 'Client';                                                                                                 

   define Opportunity_Owner/across 'Champ';                                                                                             

   define Last_Modified_Date/across format = MMDDYY. 'Modified';                                                                        

   define Total_Media_Value/across format = dollar25. 'Tot_Budget';                                                                     

   define Digital_Total_Media_Value/across format = dollar25. 'Digital_Bugt';                                                           

   define Deal_Comments/across 'Deal_Comments' width = 150;                                                                             

   rbreak after / summarize ol ul;                                                                                                      

   run;                                                                                                                                 

   ods listing close;                                                                                                                   

   ods pdf close;
```

After running this code log shows an error that

> The width of Deal_Comments is not Between 1 to 121. Adjust the column
>   width. Page size is too small for Column Titles.

Can you please suggest a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your LS and PS options are set too small.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you have the ODS LISTING destination open and the error is related to that destination. You can either modify the ls option for the destination or you can turn it off.

```
ODS LISTING CLOSE;
...your sas code
ODS LISTING;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same log

Comment: Have you tried changing your ls/ps options per @Tom's suggestion above?